How to speedup pytest-cov when faced with slow imports from external packages
I have some situations where pytest becomes extremely slow because of a combination of --cov option and import from external packages. I'm using gpt_researcher in this example, but I've seen similar slowdowns with other packages in the past.
I have a minimal example where the imported file is trivial and has no dependencies, but the difference in test duration without and with --cov goes from 1.3s to 6.9s.
In my test, I am importing a single enum from a single package: gpt_researcher.
This is the local source tree (no hidden configuration files):
.
├── foo
│   ├── enum.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test_foo.py

The file foo/enum.py is the exact copy of the offending file imported from gpt_researcher. It is a self-contained file and has no other direct imports or dependencies:
# enum.py
from enum import Enum
class ReportType(Enum):
    ResearchReport = 'research_report'
    ResourceReport = 'resource_report'
    OutlineReport = 'outline_report'
    CustomReport = 'custom_report'
    DetailedReport = 'detailed_report'
    SubtopicReport = 'subtopic_report'

The file foo/foo.py is only importing the enum and implementing a trivial function:
# foo/foo.py
from gpt_researcher.utils.enum import ReportType # this is slow
# from foo.enum import ReportType # this is fast
def foo() -> str:
    return ReportType.ResearchReport.value

The file test_foo.py just contains 1 test:
# test_foo.py
from foo.foo import foo
def test_foo():
    assert foo() == "research_report"

These are the timings that I get:

importing from the local copy of enum.py (in foo/foo.py, commenting out the first line and uncomenting from foo.enum import ReportType):

pytest ./test_foo.py: 0.01s
pytest --cov=foo ./test_foo.py: 0.03s


importing from gpt_researcher (leaving the code as above):

pytest ./test_foo.py: 1.28s
pytest --cov=foo ./test_foo.py: 6.89s



Leaving or erasing the various cache files and directories (.coverage, .pytest_cache. __pycache__, etc.) has no noticeable effect.
The package gpt_researcher does have lots of dependencies from google, langchain, nvidia, and many more. It also has an __init__.py that imports a bunch of things, but I double-checked by asking python to execute the function foo() directly, and that takes less than 1 second:
echo -e "from foo.foo import foo\nprint(foo())" | /usr/bin/time -f "%E" python
USER_AGENT environment variable not set, consider setting it to identify your requests.
research_report
0:00.95

How can I identify what is actually taking pytest-cov so much time? And, more importantly, how can I get more reasonable collecting times with --cov?
platform linux -- Python 3.12.4, pytest-8.2.2, pluggy-1.5.0
plugins: cov-5.0.0, anyio-4.4.0
gpt-researcher: 0.7.0

